# How can I change what a pointer points to within a function in C?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, memory

I'm trying to code a resizable array, which expands when it's full. All functions are working, but the resize one isn't.

```
int main(void)
{
   int arr[4];
   int *ptr = arr;
   initializeEmptyArray(ptr);
   insertAtIndex(ptr, 0, 4);
   insertAtIndex(ptr, 0, 3);
   insertAtIndex(ptr, 0, 2);
   insertAtIndex(ptr, 0, 1);
   resizeArray(&ptr);
   for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
   {
       printf("%i", arr[i]);
   }
}
```

This initiates my array [1,2,3,4] and then calls the resize array to test it.

```
void resizeArray(int **arr)
{
    int *newArr = (int *)malloc(capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = (*arr)[i];
    }
    for (int i = capacity; i < capacity * 2; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = EMPTY;
    }
    free(*arr);
    *arr = newArr;
}
```

The problem is the value of `arr` when I print it doesn't change to [1,2,3,4,-1,-1,-1,-1] (-1 represents empty). How can I change the pointer to point to this new array?

Capacity stands for the number of elements the array support, initiated as 4
EMPTY is defined as -1, to represent a empty slot in the array.

Comment: Please update question so it's a [mre].  What is capacity, EMPTY, insertAtIndex, Missing includes.

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Your initial array is on the stack and not initially allocated with malloc.  Hence, when your resize function attempts to invoke `free` on it, undefined behavior.  I'm surprised it doesn't crash.

Comment: It's my first question here, thanks for hints. I adjusted what you asked. thanks

Comment: Makes sense, but even without free(), the result is the same. It was a sad try to fix it.

Comment: You are updating `ptr` to point to a new array, but then printing `arr` (the old, local variable array).

Comment: And how can I access the updated array?

Comment: Use `ptr` not `arr`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two main issues with the code is that `arr` is allocated on the stack in `main()`, and then you `free()` it in `resizerArray()`.  That is a defect, and I fixed that my heap allocating `arr` in `main()` instead.  In your loop, you print `arr[i]` but pass `ptr` to `resizeArray()` which is updated, but `arr` still points to memory that is now free'ed.  I fixed this issue by eliminated the `ptr` variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define EMPTY 0

void resizeArray(int **arr, size_t capacity) {
    int *newArr = malloc(2 * capacity * sizeof(int));
    // for (int i = 0; i < 2 * capacity; i++) {
    //  newArr[i] = i < capacity ? (*arr)[i] : EMPTY;
    // }
    memcpy(newArr, *arr, capacity * sizeof(int));
    memset(newArr + capacity, EMPTY, capacity * sizeof(int));
    free(*arr);
    *arr = newArr;
}

int main(void) {
    size_t capacity = 4;
    int *arr = malloc(capacity * sizeof(int));
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
    arr[2] = 3;
    arr[3] = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        printf("before: %d\n", arr[i]);
    }
    resizeArray(&arr, capacity);
    capacity *= 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        printf("after: %d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

I comment out the loop in resizeArray so you can see how you would do that.  The code prints:

```
before: 1
before: 2
before: 3
before: 4
after: 1
after: 2
after: 3
after: 4
after: 0
after: 0
after: 0
after: 0
```

Both `resizeArray()` and the calling code has to know about the factor `2`.  This is not a great design.  Maybe pass in old and new capacity?  Or pass in `size_t *capacity` that can be updated if you want to hard-code the factor in `resizeArray()`?  Remember to check the return value of `malloc()` to ensure it did not fail.

See `realloc()` for the standard way to resize heap allocated memory,  and `calloc()` for how to get pre-initialized memory.

Comment: Can you explain me these lines? for (int i = 0; i < 2 * capacity; i++)
    {
        newArr[i] = i < capacity ? (*arr)[i] : EMPTY;
    }
    memcpy(newArr, *arr, capacity * sizeof(int));
    memset(newArr + capacity, EMPTY, capacity);

Comment: I'm having another problem. How can I call the resize function within another function that receives `*arr` as an argument? When I do it, it resizes properly but the  slots added become garbage values, not EMPTY as set before. ```void appendInTheEnd(int *arr, int value)
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        resizeArray(&arr, capacity);
    }
}
```

Comment: @LorenzoBattistela in your original code you had two loops first going from 0 to capacity, and second from capacity to 2 * capacity.  I combined them into one loop from 0 to 2 * capacity.  For the first half it copies from the arr, and  the 2nd half initializes it to EMPTY.  It uses a tertiary operator `condition ? expression when true : expression when false` so whole thing returns an expression.  If appendInTheEnd() has a need to change *arr, then just like resikzeArray() you need to pass in int **arr.

Comment: @LorenzoBattistela Please upvote the answers that were useful and accept he best answer so we know you are all set.  Open a new question if needed.

Comment: Yeah, your answer helped me a lot, but as I'm knew, i don't have the reputation for upvoting. Now I could resize my array calling resizeArray inside of append, but the other part of the function (that assings: `arr[size] = value;` is not working. As in: result expected: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1
result got: 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1
Thanks for all your help

Comment: Not clear what you have a problem with but just file a new question.  If you listen to what I said and post a [mre] it will be easy to help you when we see the code.

Comment: I would still suggest using realloc instead of a malloc, memcpy and free

Comment: Agree but one of the comments suggested that this was not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize an array. It's size is fixed.

So if you want something that can be resized do:

```
int arr[4]; --> int* arr = malloc(4 * sizeof *arr);
```

BTW:

It seems you miss a line like:

```
capacity = 2 * capacity ;
```

Comment: Exactly, I can't resize an array. But you can create a way that  when array is full, you create a copy with doubled size, which translates to a resizable array.

Comment: @LorenzoBattistela No, you can't assign `arr` a new value. It's as easy as that. `*arr = newArr;` is just illegal

Comment: Oh, now i understand.

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at ["realloc"](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-in-a/0596006977/re192.html), your question sounds like a perfect match

Comment: Nope - `arr` is an array - it can't be changed

Comment: @4386427:  The resizeArray() implementation uses malloc, so I was hinting at doing the implementation not using an array in the first place

Answer (score 0):

You can not resize an array with automatic storage duration. You can do this with arrays that have allocated storage duration.

So you should remove the array declaration in main and write

```
int *ptr = malloc( 4 * sizeof( int ) );
```

or

```
int *ptr = malloc( capacity * sizeof( int ) );
```

Also you forgot to change the value of the variable `capacity`. I suppose that it is not declared as a constant variable.

In this case the function `resizeArray` can look for example the following way

```
int resizeArray( int **arr )
{
    int *newArr = realloc( *arr, capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));

    int success = newArr != NULL;

    if ( success ) 
    {
        *arr = newArr;

        for (int i = capacity; i < capacity * 2; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = EMPTY;
        }

        capacity *= 2;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Pay attention to that a reallocation of the array can fail. So the function should signal to the caller whether the reallocation was successful.

Also it is not a good idea to use the variable `capacity` as a global variable.

You could write in main

```
int capacity = 4;
int *ptr = malloc( capacity * sizeof( int ) );

// ...
```

and call the function like

```
resizeArray( &ptr, &capacity );
```

In this case the function will look the following way

```
int resizeArray( int **arr, int *capacity )
{
    int *newArr = realloc( *arr, *capacity * 2 * sizeof(int));

    int success = newArr != NULL;

    if ( success ) 
    {
        *arr = newArr;

        for (int i = *capacity; i < *capacity * 2; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = EMPTY;
        }

        *capacity *= 2;
    }

    return success;
}
```